# Combine redux reducers without adding nesting

Tags: javascript, redux

I have a scenario where I have 2 reducers that are the result of a `combineReducers`.  I want to combine them together, but keep their keys at the same level on nesting.

For example, given the following reducers

```
const reducerA = combineReducers({ reducerA1, reducerA2 })
const reducerB = combineReducers{{ reducerB1, reducerB2 })
```

I want to end up with a structure like:

```
{
    reducerA1: ...,
    reducerA2: ...,
    reducerB1: ...,
    reducerB2: ...
}
```

If I use `combineReducers` again on `reducerA` and `reducerB` like so:

```
const reducer = combineReducers({ reducerA, reducersB })
```

I end up with a structure like:

```
{
    reducerA: {
        reducerA1: ...,
        reducerA2: ...
    },
    reducerB: {
        reducerB1: ...,
        reducerB2: ...
    }
}
```

I can't combine `reducerA1`, `reducerA2`, `reducerB1` and `reducerB2` in a single `combineReducers` call as `reducerA` and `reducerB` are being provided to me already combined from different npm packages.

I have tried using the [reduce-reducers](https://github.com/acdlite/reduce-reducers) library to combine them togethers and reduce the state together, an idea I got from looking at the [redux docs](https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/beyond-combinereducers#sharing-data-between-slice-reducers), like so:

```
const reducer = reduceReducers(reducerA, reducerB)
```

Unfortunately this did not work as the resulting reducer from `combineReducers` producers a warning if unknown keys are found and ignores them when returning its state, so the resulting structure only contains that of `reducerB`:

```
{
    reducerB1: ...,
    reducerB2: ...
}
```

I don't really want to implement my own `combineReducers` that does not enforce the structure so strictly if I don't have to, so I'm hoping someone knows of another way, either built-in to redux or from a library that can help me with this. Any ideas?

---

#### Edit:

There was an answer provided (it appears to have been deleted now) that suggested using [flat-combine-reducers](https://github.com/SanCoder-Q/flat-combine-reducers/blob/master/src/flat-combine-reducers.js) library:

```
const reducer = flatCombineReducers(reducerA, reducerB)
```

This was one step closer than reduce-reducers in that it managed to keep the keep the state from both `reducerA` and `reducerB`, but the warning messages are still being produced, which makes me wonder if the vanishing state I observed before was not `combineReducers` throwing it away, but rather something else going on with the reduce-reducers implementation.

The warning messages are:

> Unexpected keys "reducerB1", "reducerB2" found in previous state received by the reducer. Expected to find one of the known reducer keys instead: "reducerA1", "reducerA2". Unexpected keys will be ignored.
>
> Unexpected keys "reducerA1", "reducerA2" found in previous state received by the reducer. Expected to find one of the known reducer keys instead: "reducerB1", "reducerB2". Unexpected keys will be ignored.

If I do a production build, the warning disappear (such is the way for many react/redux warnings), but I'd rather them not appear at all.

I've also done some more searching for other libraries and found [redux-concatenate-reducers](https://github.com/ryo33/redux-concatenate-reducers):

```
const reducer = concatenateReducers([reducerA, reducerB])
```

This has the same result as flat-combine-reducers so the search continues.

---

#### Edit 2:

A few people have made some suggestions now but none have worked so far, so here is a test to help:

```
import { combineReducers, createStore } from 'redux'

describe('Sample Tests', () => {

    const reducerA1 = (state = 0) => state
    const reducerA2 = (state = { test: "value1"}) => state
    const reducerB1 = (state = [ "value" ]) => state
    const reducerB2 = (state = { test: "value2"}) => state
    
    const reducerA = combineReducers({ reducerA1, reducerA2 })
    const reducerB = combineReducers({ reducerB1, reducerB2 })

    const mergeReducers = (...reducers) => (state, action) => {
        return /* your attempt goes here */
    }

    it('should merge reducers', () => {
        const reducer = mergeReducers(reducerA, reducerB)

        const store = createStore(reducer)

        const state = store.getState()

        const expectedState = {
            reducerA1: 0,
            reducerA2: {
                test: "value1"
            },
            reducerB1: [ "value" ],
            reducerB2: {
                test: "value2"
            }
        }

        expect(state).to.deep.equal(expectedState)
    })
})
```

The goal is to get this test to pass **AND** not produce any warnings in the console.

---

#### Edit 3:

Added more tests to cover more cases, including handling an action after the initial creation and if the store is created with initial state.

```
import { combineReducers, createStore } from 'redux'

describe('Sample Tests', () => {

    const reducerA1 = (state = 0) => state
    const reducerA2 = (state = { test: "valueA" }) => state
    const reducerB1 = (state = [ "value" ]) => state
    const reducerB2 = (state = {}, action) => action.type == 'ADD_STATE' ? { ...state, test: (state.test || "value") + "B" } : state
    
    const reducerA = combineReducers({ reducerA1, reducerA2 })
    const reducerB = combineReducers({ reducerB1, reducerB2 })

    // from Javaguru's answer
    const mergeReducers = (reducer1, reducer2) => (state, action) => ({
        ...state,
        ...reducer1(state, action),
        ...reducer2(state, action)
    })

    it('should merge combined reducers', () => {
        const reducer = mergeReducers(reducerA, reducerB)

        const store = createStore(reducer)

        const state = store.getState()

        const expectedState = {
            reducerA1: 0,
            reducerA2: {
                test: "valueA"
            },
            reducerB1: [ "value" ],
            reducerB2: {}
        }

        expect(state).to.deep.equal(expectedState)
    })

    it('should merge basic reducers', () => {
        const reducer = mergeReducers(reducerA2, reducerB2)

        const store = createStore(reducer)

        const state = store.getState()

        const expectedState = {
            test: "valueA"
        }

        expect(state).to.deep.equal(expectedState)
    })

    it('should merge combined reducers and handle actions', () => {
        const reducer = mergeReducers(reducerA, reducerB)

        const store = createStore(reducer)

        store.dispatch({ type: "ADD_STATE" })

        const state = store.getState()

        const expectedState = {
            reducerA1: 0,
            reducerA2: {
                test: "valueA"
            },
            reducerB1: [ "value" ],
            reducerB2: {
                test: "valueB"
            }
        }

        expect(state).to.deep.equal(expectedState)
    })

    it('should merge basic reducers and handle actions', () => {
        const reducer = mergeReducers(reducerA2, reducerB2)

        const store = createStore(reducer)

        store.dispatch({ type: "ADD_STATE" })

        const state = store.getState()

        const expectedState = {
            test: "valueAB"
        }

        expect(state).to.deep.equal(expectedState)
    })

    it('should merge combined reducers with initial state', () => {
        const reducer = mergeReducers(reducerA, reducerB)

        const store = createStore(reducer, { reducerA1: 1, reducerB1: [ "other" ] })

        const state = store.getState()

        const expectedState = {
            reducerA1: 1,
            reducerA2: {
                test: "valueA"
            },
            reducerB1: [ "other" ],
            reducerB2: {}
        }

        expect(state).to.deep.equal(expectedState)
    })

    it('should merge basic reducers with initial state', () => {
        const reducer = mergeReducers(reducerA2, reducerB2)

        const store = createStore(reducer, { test: "valueC" })

        const state = store.getState()

        const expectedState = {
            test: "valueC"
        }

        expect(state).to.deep.equal(expectedState)
    })

    it('should merge combined reducers with initial state and handle actions', () => {
        const reducer = mergeReducers(reducerA, reducerB)

        const store = createStore(reducer, { reducerA1: 1, reducerB1: [ "other" ] })

        store.dispatch({ type: "ADD_STATE" })

        const state = store.getState()

        const expectedState = {
            reducerA1: 1,
            reducerA2: {
                test: "valueA"
            },
            reducerB1: [ "other" ],
            reducerB2: {
                test: "valueB"
            }
        }

        expect(state).to.deep.equal(expectedState)
    })

    it('should merge basic reducers with initial state and handle actions', () => {
        const reducer = mergeReducers(reducerA2, reducerB2)

        const store = createStore(reducer, { test: "valueC" })

        store.dispatch({ type: "ADD_STATE" })

        const state = store.getState()

        const expectedState = {
            test: "valueCB"
        }

        expect(state).to.deep.equal(expectedState)
    })
})
```

The above `mergeReducers` implementation passes all the tests, but still producers warnings to the console.

```
  Sample Tests
    ✓ should merge combined reducers
    ✓ should merge basic reducers
Unexpected keys "reducerB1", "reducerB2" found in previous state received by the reducer. Expected to find one of the known reducer keys instead: "reducerA1", "reducerA2". Unexpected keys will be ignored.
Unexpected keys "reducerA1", "reducerA2" found in previous state received by the reducer. Expected to find one of the known reducer keys instead: "reducerB1", "reducerB2". Unexpected keys will be ignored.
    ✓ should merge combined reducers and handle actions
    ✓ should merge basic reducers and handle actions
    ✓ should merge combined reducers with initial state
    ✓ should merge basic reducers with initial state
    ✓ should merge combined reducers with initial state and handle actions
    ✓ should merge basic reducers with initial state and handle actions
```

It is important to note that the warnings being printed are for the test case immediately after and that `combineReducers` reducers will only print each unique warning once, so because I'm reusing the reducer between tests, the warnings are only shown for the first test case to produce it (I could combine the reducers in each test to prevent this, but as the criteria I'm looking for it to not produce them at all, I'm happy with this for now).

If you are attempting this, I don't mind if `mergeReducers` accepts 2 reducers (like above), an array of reducers or an object of reducers (like `combineReducers`).  Actually, I don't mind how it is achieved as long as it doesn't require any changes to the creation of `reducerA`, `reducerB`, `reducerA1`, `reducerA1`, `reducerB1` or `reducerB2`.

---

#### Edit 4:

My current solution is modified from Jason Geomaat's answer.

The idea is to filter the state being provided to the reducer using the keys of previous calls by using the following wrapper:

```
export const filteredReducer = (reducer) => {
    let knownKeys = Object.keys(reducer(undefined, { type: '@@FILTER/INIT' }))

    return (state, action) => {
        let filteredState = state

        if (knownKeys.length && state !== undefined) {
            filteredState = knownKeys.reduce((current, key) => {
                current[key] = state[key];
                return current
            }, {})
        }

        let newState = reducer(filteredState, action)

        let nextState = state

        if (newState !== filteredState) {
            knownKeys = Object.keys(newState)
            nextState = {
                ...state,
                ...newState
            }
        }

        return nextState;
    };
}
```

I merge the result of the filtered reducers using the redux-concatenate-reducers library (could have used flat-combine-reducers but the merge implementation of the former seems a bit more robust).  The `mergeReducers` function looks like:

```
const mergeReducers = (...reducers) => concatenateReducers(reducers.map((reducer) => filterReducer(reducer))
```

This is called like so:

```
const store = createStore(mergeReducers(reducerA, reducerB)
```

This passes all of the tests and doesn't produce any warnings from reducers created with `combineReducers`.

The only bit I'm not sure about is where the `knownKeys` array is being seeded by calling the reducer with an `INIT` action.  It works, but it feels a little dirty.  If I don't do this, the only warning that is produced is if the store is created with an initial state (the extra keys are not filtered out when resolving the initial state of the reducer.

Comment: Wouldn't the simplest way to do that be: const combinedReducersAB = (state, action) => reducerB(reducerA(state, action), action); ??

Comment: This has the same issue as your answer.

Comment: Hello @MichaelPeyper, can this solution still be applied? And I'm wondering does this solution solve `n` levels deep or can it solve more than 2 combined reducers?

Comment: We used it for deeply nested structures with many more than 2 reducers at each level with no issues.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, decided to do it for fun, not too much code...  This will wrap a reducer and only provide it with keys that it has returned itself.

```
// don't provide keys to reducers that don't supply them
const filterReducer = (reducer) => {
  let lastState = undefined;
  return (state, action) => {
    if (lastState === undefined || state == undefined) {
      lastState = reducer(state, action);
      return lastState;
    }
    var filteredState = {};
    Object.keys(lastState).forEach( (key) => {
      filteredState[key] = state[key];
    });
    var newState = reducer(filteredState, action);
    lastState = newState;
    return newState;
  };
}
```

In your tests:

```
const reducerA = filterReducer(combineReducers({ reducerA1, reducerA2 }))
const reducerB = filterReducer(combineReducers({ reducerB1, reducerB2 }))
```

***NOTE:***  This does break with the idea that the reducer will always provide the same output given the same inputs.  It would probably be better to accept the list of keys when creating the reducer:

```
const filterReducer2 = (reducer, keys) => {
  let lastState = undefined;
  return (state, action) => {
    if (lastState === undefined || state == undefined) {
      lastState = reducer(state, action);
      return lastState;
    }
    var filteredState = {};
    keys.forEach( (key) => {
      filteredState[key] = state[key];
    });
    return lastState = reducer(filteredState, action);
  };
}

const reducerA = filterReducer2(
  combineReducers({ reducerA1, reducerA2 }),
  ['reducerA1', 'reducerA2'])
const reducerB = filterReducer2(
  combineReducers({ reducerB1, reducerB2 }),
  ['reducerB1', 'reducerB2'])
```

Comment: The issue is not replicating what `combineReducers` does, but rather dealing with reducers created by it.  As stated in the question, the reducers I am need to handle are coming from other npm packages and have already been combined with `combineReducers`.  How they are being combined is outside of my control, and I won't insist anyone not use a very well documented built in function.  If it's not possible, that's fine, I will have to search for another way

Comment: Cool, I'll try it out soon. The option to provide the keys up front is a no go as I've got no idea what the reducers with return.

Comment: Oh man, this is so close.  It fails the `'should merge basic reducers and handle actions'` case because it doesn't merge the shared key.  I could live with that as the common case would be a reducer created from `combineReducers` and hopefully there wont be any shared keys.  The `'should merge combined reducers with initial state'` case is still producing warnings, but again, this could be acceptable as it's less likely the store will be created with an initial state (the whole point is that I don't know what the exact state structure is going to look like).

Comment: I really like your approach of treating the filtering at a per-reducer level, removes a lot of the complexity of what I've been working on (effectively the same concept of what you have here but being managed by the `mergeReducers` wrapper.  I'm going to tinker around with this a bit and see what I can come up with.

Comment: Weird, I copied your tests to write that and both passed all tests...   DOH!  I forgot I changed mergeReducers too.  Ok, double-weird, I was having some trouble with that and I just re-copied your tests and added the `filterReducer` and wrapped reducer A and B like in my answer and all 8 tests pass again...

Comment: Looking at those tests, did you intend the input state of one reducer to affect the input state of the other reducer?  Seems like they should be called in order with the same state at that point instead of using mergeReducers if not using combineReducers...

Comment: In my head (and this is probably due to starting with [reduce-reducers](https://github.com/acdlite/reduce-reducers), I imagined the merge being more of a reduce operation on the state.  I can deal with using the previous state on all reducers if it's easier for the solution.  I've been using your approach (and some of your code) to make good progress.  I'll update the question with what I have so far soon.

Comment: I've accepted this answer, but please see my edit (Edit 4) in the question.  It's heavily based on this answer, but does solve a few of the edge cases discussed in the comments.

Answer (score 2):

OK, although the problem was already solved in the meantime, I just wanted to share what solution I came up:

```
    import { ActionTypes } from 'redux/lib/createStore'

    const mergeReducers = (...reducers) => {
        const filter = (state, keys) => (
          state !== undefined && keys.length ?

            keys.reduce((result, key) => {
              result[key] = state[key];
              return result;
            }, {}) :

            state
        );

        let mapping  = null;

        return (state, action) => {
            if (action && action.type == ActionTypes.INIT) {
                // Create the mapping information ..
                mapping = reducers.map(
                  reducer => Object.keys(reducer(undefined, action))
                );
            }
            return reducers.reduce((next, reducer, idx) => {
                const filteredState = filter(next, mapping[idx]);
                const resultingState = reducer(filteredState, action);

                return filteredState !== resultingState ?
                  {...next, ...resultingState} : 
                  next;

            }, state);
        };
    };
```

---

Previous Answer:

In order to chain an array of reducers, the following function can be used:

```
const combineFlat = (reducers) => (state, action) => reducers.reduce((newState, reducer) => reducer(newState, action), state));
```

In order to combine multiple reducers, simply use it as follows:

```
const combinedAB = combineFlat([reducerA, reducerB]);
```

Comment: Your `combineFlat` function falls into the same trap as [reduce-reducers](https://github.com/acdlite/reduce-reducers) where the state is left as that of the final reducer.

Comment: Sorry, I only just saw your update (Stack overflow doesn't notify if someone's fits and answer on your question). I'll try it out later, but I think it's going to have a warning if a second action is dispatched or if the store is created with an initial state as the incoming state has unexpected keys for the combined reducers.

Comment: As I suspected, this works until the initial state is created, but if an initial state is provided when the store is created or if an action is dispatched, the warnings appear.  I've updated the question with more tests to cover these cases.

Comment: @MichaelPeyper: I updated the answer according to your tests. It should also work during/after dispatching actions.

Comment: This is in the same boat as [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43290107/combine-redux-reducers-without-adding-nesting/43293934?noredirect=1#comment73676159_43302975) - failing `'should merge basic reducers and handle actions'` and producing warnings on `'should merge combined reducers with initial state'`.  Both those cases are less important to me, but I'd like to solve them if I can.

Comment: @MichaelPeyper maybe you can provide a test case illustrating the issue with the provided answer?

Comment: I have.  The tests in Edit 3 is scrollable and the mentioned cases are in there.

Comment: @MichaelPeyper: As you already accepted the other answer, I just wanted to share the solution that I came up with.

Comment: thanks for all the effort you put in on this one.  The other answer is ultimately what I ran with but your attempts were always welcome and useful.

Answer (score 1):

**Solution for those using Immutable**

The solutions above don't handle immutable stores, which is what I needed when I stumbled upon this question. Here is a solution I came up with, hopefully it can help someone else out.

```
import { fromJS, Map } from 'immutable';
import { combineReducers } from 'redux-immutable';

const flatCombineReducers = reducers => {
  return (previousState, action) => {
    if (!previousState) {
      return reducers.reduce(
        (state = {}, reducer) =>
          fromJS({ ...fromJS(state).toJS(), ...reducer(previousState, action).toJS() }),
        {},
      );
    }
    const combinedReducers = combineReducers(reducers);
    const combinedPreviousState = fromJS(
      reducers.reduce(
        (accumulatedPreviousStateDictionary, reducer, reducerIndex) => ({
          ...accumulatedPreviousStateDictionary,
          [reducerIndex]: previousState,
        }),
        {},
      ),
    );
    const combinedState = combinedReducers(combinedPreviousState, action).toJS();
    const isStateEqualToPreviousState = state =>
      Object.values(combinedPreviousState.toJS()).filter(previousStateForComparison =>
        Map(fromJS(previousStateForComparison)).equals(Map(fromJS(state))),
      ).length > 0;
    const newState = Object.values(combinedState).reduce(
      (accumulatedState, state) =>
        isStateEqualToPreviousState(state)
          ? {
              ...state,
              ...accumulatedState,
            }
          : {
              ...accumulatedState,
              ...state,
            },
      {},
    );

    return fromJS(newState);
  };
};

const mergeReducers = (...reducers) => flatCombineReducers(reducers);

export default mergeReducers;
```

This is then called this way:

```
mergeReducers(reducerA, reducerB)
```

It produces no errors. I am basically returning the flattened output of the [redux-immutable](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-immutable) `combineReducers` function.

I have also released this as an npm package here: [redux-immutable-merge-reducers](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-immutable-merge-reducers).

Answer (score -1):

There is also combinedReduction reducer utility

```
const reducer = combinedReduction(
  migrations.reducer,
  {
    session: session.reducer,
    entities: {
      users: users.reducer,
    },
  },
);
```